# isLocalValueSet of a UIInput always returns true in custom validator

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I wrote a custom validator to validate all the form fields. I am using Incefaces 3.2 and JSF 2.0. I noticed multiple issues on a UIInput of integer type. If I do not enter any data on the form and click on submit, I can check the field value in my custom validator by using myUIInput.getValue() and fire the required validation.

When I input some value in the field and submit, I use getSubmittedValue() in my custom validator to validate it. So far so good. When I remove the value from the field (empty it) from the UI and submit it, getValue() is still retaining the old value. isLocalValueSet() is always returning null.

I have tried resetting the below after firing the validation for the first time. It did not help either.

```
        myInput.setValue(null);
        myInput.setSubmittedValue(null);
        myInput.setLocalValueSet(false);
```

How do I reset my field state to initial value? How do I properly set isLocalValueSet() after firing a validation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

JSF components are validated in the order they appear in the component tree. Given that you're working with `getSubmittedValue()`, this can only mean that your custom validator is fired *before* any component is been processed. Perhaps you've attached the validator to a hidden input in the beginning of the form or so.

This thus means that when your custom validator is finished, JSF will continue processing all subsequent components in the component tree and thus redo the whole validation process on every individual component "the usual way", hereby overridding the component's state which you manipulated from your custom validator on.

I'm not sure what the concrete functional requirement is and why you need to approach it like that, this is somewhat smelly, but you could theoretically solve it by firing the custom validator *after* all components are been processed. and dealing with `getValue()` instead of `getSubmittedValue()`. Again, the concrete functional requirement is too unclear to suggest any design improvements.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. We are using JSR 303 bean validation on some forms of our jsf2, Icefaces 3 application. We had issues controlling the validation order. I thought of removing all the validation but the request object(dto) was tightly coupled to the other classes of the project. We were close to wrapping the project, it was too late to create a new dto without beans validations. So, I wrote a custom validator e.g. <f:event listener="#{bean.methodToValidateMultipleFields}" type="postValidate" />.

Comment: This validator gets fired every time I submit the form. My customer added a last minute requirement to show an integer field as blank if no value is entered. It has to be set to blank if validation (required or format) fails. For some reason getValue() and getSubmittedValue() were not getting updated correctly for integer type field. I had no issues with string or date fields.  As a workaround I used a string on UI and then changed it back to integer if it is a valid int value. I have not explored the route of adding a converter.